# How to query this case

Tags: sql, postgresql

For all cases in which the same customer rated the same product more than once, and in some point in time gave it a lower rating than before, return the customer name, the name of the product, and the lowest star rating that was given.

thats what i could do so far

```
SELECT product_name, MIN(rating_stars), customer_name
FROM products
INNER JOIN rating
INNER JOIN customers
```

that's the database I wrote

```
 CREATE TABLE product
(
    prod_id varchar(15),
    product_name varchar(30),
    product_price double precision,
    product_manufacturer varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id)
)

CREATE TABLE customer
(
    cust_id varchar(15),
    customer_name varchar (30),
    customer_adress varchar (30),
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
)

CREATE TABLE rating
(
    prod_id,
    cust_id,
    rating_date date not null,
    rating_stars int (5),

    PRIMARY KEY (rating_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES Products(prod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
)

CREATE TABLE sale
(
    sale_id,
    prod_id,
    cust_id,
    sale_quantity int,
    sale_cost double precision,

    PRIMARY KEY (sale_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES Products(prod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
)
```

Comment: Please also include sample data and expected results, read about how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, please show what you've managed to write so far on your own. While people on this site will help you, it's not a code writing service and you need to demonstrate at least some effort to solve the problem yourself

Comment: yeah I forgot to add my attempt of solving it, here it is i edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT cust_id, prod_id
     , min(rating_stars) AS min
  FROM rating
 GROUP BY cust_id, prod_id
HAVING array_agg(rating_stars ORDER BY rating_date ASC) <> array_agg(rating_stars ORDER BY rating_stars ASC)
)
SELECT c.customer_name, p.product_name, l.min
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN customer AS c
    ON c.cust_id = l.cust_id
 INNER JOIN product AS p
    ON p.prod_id = l.prod_id
```